# Create post with location using Facebook Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

How to post on Facebook with a location(using latitude and longitude) using its JavaScript SDK? Can't find any example to post with a location.

Will Open Graph action creation be required for posting location in the post?

Also, is it possible to share the url of a page and instead make use of Open Graph tags on the page to share the location details for use in Facebook post?

**JavaScript code to create post with just text message:**

```
var body = 'Reading JS SDK documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

An example in the documentation says:

```
You can make a POST request to locations edge from the following paths:
/{page_id}/locations

When posting to this edge, a Location will be created.
```

Does this mean that a location post cannot be created using Graph API for a user's feed?

Reference:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.api
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/location/

Edited:

Able to find an example to create a post with location attached as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21483908/how-to-post-to-facebook-with-location-attached-using-javascript-sdk):

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
    name: 'SomeName',
    message: 'SomeMessage',
    place: '106039436102339' // ID for Tallinn, Estonia
}, function (response) {});
```

Though the next question is, how to find location id using Latitude and Longitude?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location id by `https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=karachi&type=page&access_token=YOURTOKEN` This will give you the list of places which match karachi.