# Facebook Livemap. How to add a tag with location to live video

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

A really "rich" Facebook API [FAQ](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/videos/live-video/faq#livemap) says that:

> "Only live videos that have tagged a location will appear on the Live Map"

As a developer of Android application I need to tag my live video with a location.

Question: How do I do it?

**Update:**
The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38836621/4745988).
Need to set a "place" parameter by [updating](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/live-video/#Updating) a live_video object.

The hardest part is to implement a "place ID getter" function.

Comment: could you please share how to get the place id? thanks